# SSH error: Permission denied, please try again

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, openssh

I am new to ubuntu. Hence please forgive me if the question is too simple.

I have a ubuntu server setup using amazon ec2 instance. I need to connect my desktop (which is also a ubuntu machine) to the ubuntu server using SSH.

I have installed open-ssh in ubuntu server. I need all systems from my network to connect the ubuntu server using SSH. Hence opened SSH port 22 for my static IP in security groups (AWS).

My SSHD-CONFIG file is:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Now when I tried to connect ubuntu server from my terminal,

```
 ssh ubuntu@SERVER_IP
```

I got the following error:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

On some research I realized that, I need to monitor my server's auth log for this. I got the following error in my auth log (/var/log/auth.log)

```
Jul  2 09:38:07 ip-192-xx-xx-xxx sshd[3037]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=MY_CLIENT_IP  user=ubuntu
Jul  2 09:38:09 ip-192-xx-xx-xxx sshd[3037]: Failed password for ubuntu from MY_CLIENT_IP port 39116 ssh2
```

When I tried to debug this using: ssh -v ubuntu@SERVER_IP

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to SERVER_IP [SERVER_IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA {SERVER_HOST_KEY}
debug1: Host 'SERVER_IP' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ubuntu@SERVER_IP's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
Permission denied, please try again.
ubuntu@SERVER_IP's password:
```

Can anyone please guide me where the issue is and suggest some solution for this issue.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you checked the errors you get with `ssh -v ubuntu@SERVER_IP`?

Comment: Thanks for your response demure.. I have edited my question with the output of ssh -v ubuntu@SERVER_IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where the issue is with and fixed.

I have created a new user and reset its password. In Ubuntu, I feel that when we create a new user, by default the root user's password will be assigned to the new user. Even then, reset and assign some password to that new user.

I have switched off all SSH authentications (like RSAAuthentication, PubkeyAuthentication and KerberosAuthentication).. I have turned on only the PasswordAuthentication. Now I was able to connect all my systems (from my network) to remote server.

Thank You.